# unzip a file and pipe to “ddrescue” command

Tags: pipe, ddrescue

I have a zipped image file, and need use "ddrescue" command instead "dd" to do something like this:

```
unzip -p ubuntuXXXX.img.zip | sudo dd bs=2M of=/dev/sdb
```

But "ddrescue" needs the image file as parameter to run:

```
ddrescue -d -D --force ubuntuXXXX.img /dev/sdb
```

How can I pipe the zip file to ddrescue?

Comment: Have you tried using "-" for the infile?

Answer (score 3):

`ddrescue` is a tool that will try to help you get data from a disk that is dying, where it may be necessary to reread the same parts of a file several times until no error occurs anymore. To be able to do that, it needs to seek the input file, which is impossible on a pipe.

It's also pretty pointless to try to use `ddrescue` unless your disk is, in fact, dying. Why are you doing this in the first place?

Comment: Here is the reason why use ddrescue: "I suggest the use of "ddrescue" instead of "dd" (numerous problem with "dd" in Linux Mint 17.2)to create the image > use: " [https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi#Installation]

Comment: In my experience, ddrescue is better at finding the perfect block size, for reading with the highest performance. 64k is pretty good for many devices, but it certainly makes a difference if you are reading from a USB-Stick/SSD or from a hard disk.